# Video on what question(s) can be asked

Tags: support

Is there any video that explains what type questions can be asked on stack over flow ?

Answer (score 8):

No, there isn't such a video.

I don't really see the point of producing such a video, given that there is a help center with articles about what [is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what [shouldn't be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on Stack Overflow.